# How strict are the airlines if one's bag is only 2cm bigger than the rule?

Tags: hand-luggage

If a carryon bag is 2cm bigger than the stated measurements I was curious as to how many airlines or which airlines in particular are known to enforce the rules most or all of the time? I presume a discount airliner such as Easyjet might even make you check your bag??

Edit: I'm not looking for anecdotes as to make it broad but more towards how do airliners run the bag checks? The methods? And, how these things might make easy to bypass or not. Not looking for something that just depends on the random mood of the checker but how each airline runs their checks every. single. time.

Comment: Depends on the airline. Which one are you wondering about in particular?

Comment: In it's current form the question is going to generate potentially hundreds of anecdotes on a multitude of airlines, and random staff at different airports who might have been strict or lenient on a given day.  Too broad at present :/

Comment: Also [a possible duplicate](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8788/how-strict-are-european-budget-airlines-in-terms-of-enforcing-hand-luggage?rq=1)

Comment: Keep in mind that, depending on the specific dimensions of your bag and the allowance provided, your "just slightly too big" bag might no longer fit in the compartment on which the dimensions are based. At which point, you'll have to check the bag, *and* make a fool of yourself while doing it.

Answer (score 5):

It depends, if the airline provides one of those "IF IT FITS" boxes to check the size of the carry on, then it might be refused. For example, EasyJet:

[image]

Anyway, 2 cm will not be easily noticed by bare eyes, so if the airline does not have the baggage checker at the gate I would take the chance as long as the weight is within the limit. Remember, if the airline has the baggage checker, it is better to pay for the extra size online, it will be much cheaper than paying at the gate.

Comment: This is kind of the info I was looking for...now do all airlines have the box thing but sometimes they don't take their time to use it?

Comment: @verve no, but it is will impossible to list which airlines have it and which airlines don't. It would have been better if you mentioned which airline you are flying with as Mark mentioned in his comment.

Comment: Those 'if it fits' boxes are often a tad larger than what the airline actually states as their maximum size.

Comment: It will depend on luck. I've only seen staff ask passengers to place bags in that box when it was already obvious that they wouldn't fit, presumably so that the box would make their point for them, thus avoiding a silly argument. That includes discounters, but I haven't used those much.